# Why is vectorized Pinv slower than unvectorized?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have ten `6000 x 784` matrices. If I run np.cov and then pinv on each of them, the total time is:

```
%timeit for n in range(10): pinv(np.cov(A,rowvar = False))
1.64 s ± 78.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If I instead loop the np.cov and compute the pinv of the 3D stack, I get:

```
%timeit for n in range(10): dd[n] = np.cov(A,rowvar = False)
485 ms ± 18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pinv(dd)
4.59 s ± 369 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Why is pinv on the 3D so slow?

What can I do to have to compute np.cov of a stack and a corresponding pinv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the implementation. The limiting step is the numpy `matmul`. First I thought the SVD is the limiting step, but this scales linearily (~130 ms per iteration, 1.3 s for the pack of ten).

Here are some parts of the profiling:

1 call (your first snippet)

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.131    0.131    0.131    0.131 linalg.py:1299(svd)
    1    0.011    0.011    0.011    0.011 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.matmul}
    1    0.003    0.003    0.144    0.144 <ipython-input-76-2a63f1c84429>:1(pinv)
```

1 call of a pack of 10 (your second snippet)

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    2.952    2.952    2.952    2.952 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.matmul}
    1    1.265    1.265    1.265    1.265 linalg.py:1299(svd)
    1    0.026    0.026    4.266    4.266 <ipython-input-76-2a63f1c84429>:1(pinv)
```

Maybe there is an internal issue of the C-ordering (but recent numpy versions should take care of it), or it is just inefficient in this case... Tried briefly to change to the BLAS interface directly using the [scipy implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.blas.sgemm.html), but this operates on two-dimensional matrices only. These issues (that matmul is slow) has been actually raised [elsewhere](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7569).

Bottom line, do it non-vectorized or try to use other implementations. Sometimes the fastet way for matrix multiplication is to use the `eigen` functions, but I never tried it in a multi-dimensional problem.